# DataGridView add checkbox and allow to select only records based on variable value via checkbox

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

In vb.net I have DataGidView showing all columns from my Access database. Then in form `Load` event I added this code to add check box column to DataGridView.

```vb
Dim chk As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(chk)
chk.HeaderText = "Select Question"
chk.Name = "chk"
```

Here I want user to only select those many records as my `maxquestions` variable integer value and do not let user select more questions. I also want that user cannot change values of my DataGridView. And thereafter I want to export selected questions to a new table `mynewtable` already created in database.

Thanks, help appreciated.

**I have done something and it somehow works fine...**

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
        If (TryCast(DataGridView1.CurrentCell, DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)) IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim count As Integer = 0
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                Dim isChecked As Boolean = CBool(row.Cells(6).EditedFormattedValue)
                If isChecked Then
                    count = count + 1
                Else
                    ' count -= 1
                End If
            Next
            If count > mark_1_questions Then
                Label3.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Else
                Label3.ForeColor = Color.Black
            End If
            Label3.Text = "You Have Selected: " & count & " Questions."

            If count = mark_11_questions Then
                MessageBox.Show(Me, "Maximum/Required Questions Selected : " & mark_11_questions, "Caution")
                'DataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically
                Button1.Enabled = True
            ElseIf count > mark_11_questions Then
                MessageBox.Show(Me, "Please unselect some questions : " & count - mark_11_questions, "Caution")
                Button1.Enabled = False
            Else
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

**Now the question is how to export selected records through checkbox to table altogether.**

Comment: Did you even try to search and find example code? Review https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Insert-Save-Selected-Checked-rows-from-DataGridView-to-Database-in-Windows-Forms-WinForms-Application-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the count like this.

```
Private Function GetCheckedCount() As Integer
    Dim CheckedRows As Integer
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If CBool(row.Cells(8).Value) Then
            CheckedRows += 1
        End If
    Next
    Return CheckedRows
End Function
```